# Android countdown timer

Tags: java, android, timer, count, countdown

So since i tried to add timer to my app i got crash every time i tried to go inside the intent witht he timer.
i used countdown timer which is android built i understand, i saw in youtube how to build it hope you can help me :)

The crash logs are :

```
04-16 13:33:45.485: I/Timeline(20817): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.flagsgame time:34509170
04-16 13:33:45.485: D/Flagss Game(20817): inside time
04-16 13:33:45.955: D/AndroidRuntime(20817): Shutting down VM
04-16 13:33:45.955: W/dalvikvm(20817): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162cdb8)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817): Process: com.example.flagsgame,  PID: 20817
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flagsgame/com.example.flagsgame.TimeAttack}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at com.example.flagsgame.TimeAttack.onCreate(TimeAttack.java:88)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-16 13:33:45.965: E/AndroidRuntime(20817):    ... 11 more
```

my code:

```
public class TimeAttack extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

String pic;//תמונה של הדגל
Button answer1;//תשובות
Button answer2;
Button answer3;
Button answer4;
Button hint;
TextView guess;
TextView numOfGuess;
TextView score;
TextView scorenum;
TextView textViewTime;
MediaPlayer mpHint;
MediaPlayer mpNext;
MediaPlayer mpWrong;
Animation animationfadein;
Animation animationfadeout;
String fn;
Guesses G;
Score s;
Button [] b = new Button[4];
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
List<String>WrongAnswers=new ArrayList<String>();

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    score =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    scorenum =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scorenum);
    scorenum.setText(String.valueOf(s.score));
    guess =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.guesses);
    numOfGuess=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.numOfGuesses);
    numOfGuess.setText(String.valueOf(Guesses.numOfGuesses));
    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    hint =(Button)findViewById(R.id.hint);
    hint.setOnClickListener(hintOnClickListener);
    mpHint = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.hint_sound);
    mpNext = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.next_flag);
    mpWrong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong_answer);
    animationfadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    animationfadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);

    textViewTime.setText("00:01:00");
    final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(61000, 1000);

    timer.start();

    Flags f = new Flags();
    Random r = new Random();//הדגל שיבחר לשאלה
    int num = r.nextInt(160);//Up

    f = db.getFlag(num);//הצגת הדגל הרנדומלי שיצא
    fn = f.getName().toString();
    pic = f.getImage().toString();
    pic_view(pic);//מעבר לפונקציה להשמת התמונה של הדגל במשחק

    //מערך ארבע כפתורים כנגד ארבע תשובות

    b[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    List<String>Answers=new ArrayList<String>();//מערך תשובות

    Answers.add(f.getName().toString());//הוספת התשובה הנכונה
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        num = r.nextInt(200);
        String valToAdd1 = db.getFlag(num).getName().toString();
        if(!Answers.contains(valToAdd1)){
            WrongAnswers.add(valToAdd1);
            Answers.add(valToAdd1);
        }

    }

    /*num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());//הוספת 3 תשובות רנדומליות
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());
    num = r.nextInt(30);
    Answers.add(db.getFlag(num).getName().toString());*/

    Collections.shuffle(Answers);//ערבוב התשובות

    for(int i=0;i<Answers.size();i++)
    {
        b[i].setText(Answers.get(i));//השמת התשובות מהמהערך למערך הכפתורים
        b[i].startAnimation(animationfadein);
    }
}//end of OnCreat


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){//actionbar activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void resetQuiz()
{
    recreate();
}

private OnClickListener hintOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mpHint.start();
        if(Guesses.numOfGuesses==1)
        {
            G.setNumOfGuesses(3);
            finish();//כאשר מספר הניחושים
            return;
        }
        else
            G.numOfGuesses--;

        int invisblecount=0;
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            if(invisblecount<2){
                String buttonText = b[i].getText().toString();  
                if(buttonText.equals(WrongAnswers.get(0))||buttonText.equals(WrongAnswers.get(1)))
                {
                    b[i].startAnimation(animationfadeout);
                    b[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    invisblecount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

public void check(View v)
{
    Log.d("yes", fn);
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String text = b.getText().toString();
    if(text.equals(fn))
    {
        mpNext.start();
        s.score+=5;
        resetQuiz();
    }
    else
    {
        mpWrong.start();
        if(Guesses.numOfGuesses==1)
        {
            G.setNumOfGuesses(3);
            finish();//כאשר מספר הניחושים
            return;
        }
        Guesses.numOfGuesses--;
        if(s.score>0)
            s.score-=5;
        scorenum.setText(String.valueOf(s.score));
        numOfGuess.setText(String.valueOf(Guesses.numOfGuesses));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

private void pic_view(String pic2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //גישה לדגל לפי שמו וייבוא התמונה
    Log.d("Result from pic function " , pic2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    String uri ="@drawable/";
    uri += pic2;    
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, pic2, getPackageName());//הצוות התמונה 
    Drawable res= getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);//ציור התמונה
    imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
}


@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Animatoin Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textViewTime.setText("Completed.");
    }

}
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_game"
tools:context=".TimeAttack" >

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:scaleX="2"
    android:scaleY="2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numOfGuesses"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gallery1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guesses"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/guesses"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="60px" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="226dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"
        android:src="@drawable/argentina" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="check"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="check"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="check"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="check"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scorenum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="60px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scorenum"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/score"
    android:textSize="60px" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/hint"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="hint"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/score"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hint"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

last stacktrace:

```
04-16 21:08:10.418: I/Timeline(27036): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.flagsgame time:42325911
04-16 21:08:10.418: D/Flagss Game(27036): inside time
04-16 21:08:10.828: D/AndroidRuntime(27036): Shutting down VM
04-16 21:08:10.828: W/dalvikvm(27036): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162cdb8)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036): Process: com.example.flagsgame, PID: 27036
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flagsgame/com.example.flagsgame.TimeAttack}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at com.example.flagsgame.TimeAttack.onCreate(TimeAttack.java:88)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-16 21:08:10.828: E/AndroidRuntime(27036):    ... 11 more
04-16 21:08:14.688: I/Process(27036): Sending signal. PID: 27036 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: probably `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` causing issue so try using `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: @Raghunandan i put full stacktrace

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no its not beacause that i tried it and in the other activity it works fine with that but the other activity is without timer

Comment: Some object on line 88 is null. Check it

Comment: @Raghunandan iam on my way to work will check it soon as i come back in few hours

Comment: your Score s object is null;   
 scorenum.setText(String.valueOf(s.score));

Comment: @Abhishek....You should set it as Answer, it´s correct...

Comment: @Abhishek how could it be if in the other intent the same code working great and the score class working great s. Score have a value

Comment: @adids: might be you forgot to add that intent method here, as i don't see any initialization of s before that statement

Comment: @Raghunandan line 88 is this: textViewTime.setText("00:01:00"); what null here?

Comment: @Raghunandan textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime); and its good in the xml you can find it down there

Comment: Yeah but does it belong to the one that u inflate if not then wrong else that code is not the problem. Rerun repost the stack trace something else is null then

Comment: @Raghunandan i put last stacktrace

Comment: @adids1221 if this is `textViewTime.setText("00:01:00");` line 88 then `textViewTime` is null. Either it doe snot belong to the layout you inflate or the referenced id is wrong.

Comment: So what should I do hhh it's messed-up

Answer (score 0):

your Score s object is null;

```
scorenum.setText(String.valueOf(s.score));
```

Comment: i tried to put in in mark // and i still got error which mean is  not this am i right? @Abhishek Dabral

Comment: is that on the same line 88?